# Common ways for testing java spring services with JpaRepositories

Tags: java, spring, junit, service, mocking

I would like to ask for a common way to test services of a spring boot web application. My question points to the difference between testing the service itself and not a underlying repository or related filter mechanisms.

I believe I understand the need to test a situation like:
A RestController as an autowired service that has an autowired JpaRepository for a certain entity class, e.g. "Person". Assuming the service has a function to create (persist) a new Person if it does not already exists:

```java
@Service
class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;

    void create(Person p) {
        Optional<Person> op = repository.findByName(p.getName());
        if(op.isPresent()) {
            throw new CannotCreateObjectException();
        } else {
            repository.save(p);
        }
    }
    
}
```

In a unit test I should mock the repository.findByName() to simulate either an existing and non-existing person to cover both possible behaviours.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)    
public class PersonServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonService service;
    
    @Mock
    private PersonRepository repository;
    
    @Test
    void aPersonShouldBeCreated() {
        when(
            repository.findByName("GenericPersonName")
        ).thenReturn(
            Optional.empty()
        );
        
        try {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setName("GenericPersonName");
            service.create(p);
        } catch (CannotCreateObjectException e) {
            Assertions.fail(
                "Person with name 'GenericPersonName' should have been " +
                "accepted for creation"
            );
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    void aPersonShouldNotBeCreated() {
        Person existingPerson = new Person();
        existingPerson.setName("GenericPersonName");
        
        when(
            repository.findByName("GenericPersonName")
        ).thenReturn(
            Optional.of(existingPerson)
        );
        
        try {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setName("GenericPersonName");
            service.create(p);
            Assertions.fail(
                "Person with name 'GenericPersonName' should not have been " +
                "accepted for creation"
            );
        } catch (CannotCreateObjectException e) {
            ;
        }
    }
    
}
```

But I'm struggeling to find the need to test a situation like this:
The service also has a function to load multiple persons according to an attribute based filter

```java
/**
 * Load all persons according to filter, accessible to requesting user.
 * 
 * @param filter Attribute based filter
 * @return List of accessible persons
 */
public List<Person> loadAll(Person filter) {
    // prepare matching pattern
    ExampleMatcher em = prepareMatcher(); // define attributes for matching
    Example<Person> x = Example.of(filter, em);
    
    // maybe add some checks about which persons the current user is
    // allowed to see as soon as I understand spring security...
    
    // search according to filter
    List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
    repository.findAll(x).forEach(result::add);
    
    return result;
}

private ExampleMatcher prepareMatcher() {
    ExampleMatcher em = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll();
    em.withMatcher(
        "id", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.exact()
    );
    em.withMatcher(
        "name", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.contains()
    );
    em.withMatcher(
        "last_name", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.contains()
    );
    em.withMatcher(
        "first_name", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.contains()
    );
    return em;
}
```

Mocking the repository.findAll method according to the given filter would be a circular conclusion. The actual functionality lies within .findAll which I should not test as well as the ExampleMatcher.

=> Should I just test for the right prepareMatcher() result (so the ExampleMatcher respects the desired attributes)?

=> Should this be tested as JpaTest where real queries are executed with some scenarios of filters and expected results? Originally I don't wanted to mix service and database tests..

Thank you for your help

Comment: Here's a different perspective on [unit testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM&t=2100s) and specifically what should be isolated within the unit being tested.